# Convert chararray to float

Tags: type-conversion, apache-pig

I am new to pig programming. I have one txt file and comma (,) as a delimiter. In amount columns i.e; amt_IN and amy_OUT are of type chararray with data $830.03 and $1392.54 respectively.
I need these two columns in INR. I tried this by removing the $ symbol from the string first and then tried to convert it to float.

Following is txt file - petrol.csv

```
Z7O 7C2,reliance,$830.03,$1392.54,1067,722,1625
T6Q 0L9,hindustan,$994.57,$11765.97,1039,805,1626
S1J 8B8,Bharat,$881.25,$10345.43,1066,657,1627
```

I used the following code to remove the $ symbol.

```
A = LOAD 'project/petrol.txt' USING PigStorage(',') as (distributer_id:chararray,distributer_name:chararray,amt_IN:chararray,amy_OUT:chararray,vol_IN:int,vol_OUT:int,year:int);
DUMP A;

(Z7O 7C2,reliance,$830.03,$1392.54,1067,722,1625)
(T6Q 0L9,hindustan,$994.57,$11765.97,1039,805,1626)
(S1J 8B8,Bharat,$881.25,$10345.43,1066,657,1627)
```

```
X = FOREACH A GENERATE distributer_id,distributer_name,SUBSTRING(amt_IN,1),SUBSTRING(amy_OUT,1),vol_IN,vol_OUT,year;
DUMP X;

(Z7O 7C2,reliance,830.03,1392.54,1067,722,1625)
(T6Q 0L9,hindustan,994.57,11765.97,1039,805,1626)
(S1J 8B8,Bharat,881.25,10345.43,1066,657,1627)
```

I need amt_IN and amy_OUT to be converted to float so that I can convert the amount in USD to INR.

Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

In Pig, you can cast data types by using `(type)` in front of the variable. If [using Pig 0.17](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG-2315), you can also use `AS var_name:type`.

As you might not be using Pig 0.17, I expect the first approach is most likely to work.

```
X = FOREACH A GENERATE 
    distributer_id,
    distributer_name,
    (float) SUBSTRING(amt_IN,1),
    (float) SUBSTRING(amy_OUT,1),
    vol_IN,
    vol_OUT,
    year;
```